# TikzDictionary slow and blocking in knitr

Tags: tikz-pgf, r, knitr, tikzdevice

I need to knit presentations with many slides and Tikz-plots. Knitr is fantastic for this, but it takes very long time and I cant knit two reports in parallel.

I have isolated the problem to the saving on disk of tikzDictionary file. There are two problems, but I suspect they are related and have same solution.

Problem 1: tikzDictionary is re-written on the harddisk for every slide and plot. This slows down report generation.

Problem 2: If I Rscript a second report-generation before the first is ready, there is an error and the report-generation crasches:

```
Quitting from lines 10-11 (./Slide_template_example.Rnw) 
Error in createLockFile(lockname) : cannot create lock file
Calls: knit2pdf ... dbExists -> dbExists -> dbList -> dbList -> createLockFile
```

How can I define the tikzDictionary to not be re-written per slide, and not be in conflict with another R-session?

Here is a minimal working (crashing) example. Run this, each in its own in terminal-window:

```
Rscript Report_start.R "Report1"
Rscript Report_start.R "Report2"
```

R-file:

```
## Report_start.R
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
report.name <- as.character(args[1])
library(knitr)
knit2pdf(input="Report_master_example.Rnw", compiler='xelatex', output=paste(report.name, ".tex", sep=""))
```

Master-Rnw:

```
## Report_master_example.Rnw
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Beamer-example}
\author{Chris}

\begin{document}

<<data.prep, include=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')
plot.data <- data.frame(days=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), price=c(2,3,4,3,5,6,5,7,8))
@

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage%
\end{frame}

<<run-all-orig, include=FALSE>>=
out = NULL
for (i in 1:100) {
  out = c(out, knit_child('Slide_template_example.Rnw'))
}
@
\Sexpr{paste(out, collapse = '\n')}

\end{document}
```

Slide-template-Rnw:

```
## Slide_template_example.Rnw
<<, echo=FALSE >>=
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path=paste("figure/", report.name, "-nr-", i, "-", sep=""))
@

  \begin{frame}{Slide: \Sexpr{i}}
<<, echo=FALSE, dev='tikz', sanitize=TRUE, fig.width=6, fig.height=4, out.width='.40\\paperwidth', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
   p <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=days, y=price))
   p <- p + geom_line()
   p
@
  \end{frame}
```

Hopefully someone will find the example useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the two problems:

1. The dictionary file in indeed re-written for every single plot, and there is no way to avoid it. Actually the **filehash** package is used, so it will not be as slow as you may imagine. You can also turn on [caching](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) to avoid repetitive computing.
2. You can specify different dictionary file paths for different reports, e.g. after `options(tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')`, also specify:

   ```
   options(tikzMetricsDictionary = paste(report.name, 'tikzDictionary', sep = '-'))
   ```

   Then the dictionary files for your two reports will not clash.

Comment: Hi, I have now tried the suggestion, but it seems like the file is still called "Slide_template_example-tikzDictionary", with resulting blocking. Am I correct to place the above line in "Report_master_example.Rnw"?

Comment: @Chris Oops, sorry, you are right, and should put the setting in `Slide_template_example.Rnw` instead of `Report_master_example.Rnw`. If you use the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) of knitr, you should be fine if the option is set in master.

Comment: Yes, now got it working! I installed the development version and kept the new line in master. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that, at least under Windows 7 (64 bit), there appears to be a race condition in the OS (maybe there is some sort of caching of the directory that takes a while to update?), where the lockfile is sometimes deleted, but a subsequent call to create a lockfile fails because the OS reports the lockfile is still present. This happens intermittently, but frequently, on several systems I use.

Modifying filehash to try a few iterations of waiting a few hundred milliseconds and trying again when it can't create the lock file on its first attempt seems to solve this.

See the issue and pull request at the filehash git: https://github.com/rdpeng/filehash/pull/6

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question?

Comment: The question asked about crashes when using tikz and knitr. I think this explains why the crashes are happening and offers a fix that stops tikzDevice from crashing, at least for me. I'm sorry if that's not helpful.